# Touch screen keyboard on textbox

Tags: vb.net

I wrote application for my client and now it turns out that this application will be running on computer with touch screen and has no physical keyboard plugged in. Everything is working fine instead textbox control which is used to enter some text as search box. How to make that if user use this textbox to enter something to show him virtual keyboard?
cheers

Comment: Just add this line to the textbox `Focus` event: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk.exe");`. Whenever the user enters the textbox, an on screen keyboard will appear. Alternatively, you can add a little button next to the textbox that, when pushed, will also make the on screen keyboard appear.

Comment: i dont see Focus event in TextBox's events

Comment: It's called `GotFocus` or you could use `Enter` event.